# Which date class should I use in Java 8?

Tags: java, date, datetime, timestamp, java-8

There is a whole set of date's classes in Java 8:

- [**`java.time.LocalDateTime`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html);
- [**`java.time.ZonedDateTime`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html);
- [**`java.time.Instant`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html);
- [**`java.time.OffsetDateTime`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html);
- [**`java.sql.Timestamp`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html);
- [**`java.util.Date`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

I already passed over their JavaDocs and paid attention that all these classes contain all the methods I need. Thus, for the moment, I can select them randomly. But I guess that there is some reason why there are 6 separate classes and each of them is dedicated to the specific purpose.

Technical information & requirements:

1. The input is in `String`, which is converted to one of these date formats.
2. I don't need to display the time zones but when I compare two dates it's important to be capable to compare correctly the time in New York and in Paris.
3. The precise level is seconds, there is no need to use milliseconds.
4. The required operations:

- find max/min date;
- sort objects by date;
- calculate date & time period (difference between two dates);
- insert objects to MongoDB and retrieve them from a db by date (e.g. all objects after specific date).

My questions:

1. Which aspects should I bear in mind in order to choose the optimal format among these four options from the performance & maintainability points of view?
2. Is there any reason why I should avoid some of these date classes?

Comment: I'm afraid this is too broad. You should start by reading the Javadoc for those classes. There is no good answer to this.

Comment: Don't use java.util.Date in Java 8.

Comment: Define "store a date", first; you mention `java.sql.Timestamp`, does that mean you intend to store into/retrieve from an RDBMS engine? Do you need timezone information?

Comment: @Tunaki, I already passed over their JavaDocs and paid attention that all these classes contain all the methods I need, thus, for the moment I can select them randomly. But I guess, that there is some reason why there are 4 separate classes and each of them is dedicated to the specific purpose.

Comment: Well obviously i wouldn't use java.sql.Timestamp if you aren't planning to do JDBC. java.util.Date is pre-java 8 and notoriously clunky. I would go with Java 8's LocalDateTime.

Comment: @EricGuan Unless timezones are important and `ZonedDateTime` should be preferred.

Comment: @fge, I want to save a date in object's property and then compare/sort objects by this value. Furthermore, I'll store these objects in `MongoDB` and will perform the queries by date field as well.

Comment: You have to give specific details. In what form do you get the input (string?), are time zones important, are they timestamps, what operations will be performed on them and what calculation will they be used for.

Comment: @user1803551, the question has been narrowed and enriched by technical details.

Comment: @MikeB. This may be informative: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html - what matters is the underlying data you are trying to describe. Your string only has date and time information - it is essentially a LocalDateTime. But then you also mention time zones. When you get that string, do you know in what time zone it is? Also note that mongodb represents dates as a number of milliseconds since the epoch - the closest representation in Java would be an Instant. You should give a bit more background as to what those date actually represent.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Each one of the `Date` classes are for specific purposes:

- If you want to use your Date in an `SQL`/`JDBC` context, use the `java.sql.Timestamp`.
- `java.util.Date` is the old Java API, it is not thread safe, you can difficultly handle time zoning, and on the top of all, it is poorly designed: one simple uniformity is that months start from 1 while days start from 0.
- `java.time.LocalDateTime` is an immutable date-time object that represents a date-time, often viewed as year-month-day-hour-minute-second, which you need exactly.
- `java.time.ZonedDateTime` class stores all date and time fields, so you can use it to deal with values like:
  `27th January 1990 at 15:40.30.123123123 +02:00` in the Europe/Paris time-zone.

To do your task, the `ZonedDateTime` class handles conversion from the local time-line of `LocalDateTime` to the instant time-line of `Instant` (which models a single instantaneous point on the time-line). The difference between the two time-lines, represented by a `ZoneOffset`, is the offset from UTC/Greenwich.

To calculate duration and period: there is the `java.time.Duration` which is a time-based amount of time, such as '20.5 seconds', and `java.time.Period`, which is a date-based amount of time (like: 26 years, 2 months and 2 days).

To get max and min dates, you can use the Java 8 lambdas in something like:

```java
Date maxDate = list.stream().map(yourInstance -> yourInstance.date).max(Date::compareTo).get();
Date minDate = list.stream().map(yourInstance -> yourInstance.date).min(Date::compareTo).get();
```