# Getting JDBC & Saxon DateTime data as a ZonedDateTime object

Tags: jdbc, saxon, jsonpath, zoneddatetime

We have a bunch of code that gets a DateTime from JDBC, Saxon (XPath), dom4j, jway json-path (JPath), & OData as a Date object. We're now up on Java 1.8 and my first question is do I want to now try to get any data that I used to get as a Date object to now get it as a ZonedDateTime object? Or should I be using something else?

My second question is how do I read the data from JDBC, Saxon, etc as ZonedDateTime objects?

Comment: Your question is too broad and should really be asked per technology. JDBC has nothing to do with Saxon has nothing to do with jsonpath has nothing to do with etc.. For example the answer for JDBC is "you can't, at least not directly, as JDBC (since 4.2) only specifies a mapping for LocalDate/LocalTime/LocalDateTime/OffsetTime/OffsetDateTime and not for ZonedDateTime." No clue about the others.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

- Never use the legacy classes, use only *java.time*.
- When you must, convert using new methods added to the old classes.
- As of JDBC 4.2, exchange *java.time* objects with your database, never strings or `java.sql` types.
- Do most of your work in UTC. Adjust into a time zone only for presentation.
- When communicating date-time values as text, use ISO 8601 formats.
- Search Stack Overflow for more info.

---

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, `java.sql.Timestamp`, and `java.sql.Date` are all entirely supplanted by the *java.time* classes. **No need to ever touch those awful old classes again.**

The *java.time* classes have been bundled with Java 8 and later for a few years now. They have proven themselves to be a reliable, industry-leading framework for date-time work. They were inspired by the lessons learned from the excellent [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project (now in maintenance-mode). So the *java.time* classes have “an old soul”, and are not some limited “1.0” rough draft.

## Conversion

For interoperating with old code not yet updated to the *java.time* classes, you can easily convert back-and-forth between the legacy classes and modern classes. For conversions, look to new methods added to the old classes. Read Questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36639154/642706) to learn more.

### Database

As of [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) and later, you can directly exchange *java.time* objects with your database. No need to ever use the badly-designed *java.sql* classes again for date-time values.

Generally best to use `Instant` for values in a column of type akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

And retrieval.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

## ISO 8601

When exchanging date-time values outside of a JVM, serialize to text using the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. These formats are designed to be useful and practical, easy to parse by machines, easy to read by humans across cultures.

The *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. The `ZonedDateTime` class extends the standard by wisely appending the name of the zone in square brackets.

## Zones

> data that I used to get as a Date object to now get it as a ZonedDateTime object?

The `java.util.Date` class is directly replaced by `Instant`. Both represent a moment in UTC. The modern class resolves to nanoseconds instead of milliseconds.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;  // Convert from legacy class to modern.
```

In databases such as Postgres, a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` actually does *not* have its time zone saved. Instead, any offset or zone passed with an incoming value is used by the database to adjust into UTC. The resulting UTC moment is saved to the database, and the original zone/offset is discarded. If you need the original zone/offset, you must manually save it to an extra column yourself.

So, generally best to pass and fetch `Instant` objects with your database for a moment on the timeline.

To learn about the concept of a date-time *not* on the timeline, search for `LocalDateTime` class, and read postings like this Question, [*What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32437550/642706).

Be aware that the SQL standard barely touches on the tricky topic of date-time handling. It defines a few types but says little about behavior. So databases vary *widely* in their implementations. Be sure to study and experiment to verify your understanding of your database and driver.

> read the data from JDBC, Saxon, etc as ZonedDateTime objects?

Generally the best practice is to work in UTC. That means the `Instant` class rather than `ZonedDateTime` class.

If receiving a `Date`, convert to `Instant` as shown above.

Usually you want to do your business logic, storage, exchange, logging, and tracing/debugging all in UTC. Apply a time zone only where required by business requirements or for presentation to a user.

With a `Instant` in hand, you can adjust to the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region by assigning a time zone. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

## Search Stack Overflow

Your Question is really a duplicate of many others such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35301269/642706). I suggest you search Stack Overflow for the various *java.time* class names. You will learn much as there have been plenty of questions and answers already posted.

## Compatible libraries

Many Java libraries have been updated to work with *java.time* types.

Check for the latest versions of libraries you may be using, and read their documentation to learn about added support.

If not directly supported, libraries that accept converters/formatters/plugins will likely have some *java.time* ones already written. Search for them, or ask on the sister site: [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Really helpful post. Question, why Instant instead of ZonedDateTime? TIA

Comment: Excellent response, and a reminder that with the next release of Saxon moving to a Java 8 baseline, we should look again at what conversions from XDM date/time types to Java types we support.

Comment: If `Date` fulfilled your requirements in the old days, `Instant` will now. Only if you need to store a specific time zone (like Africa/Juba) (which `Date` could not do), use `ZonedDateTime`.