# What is the date type standard in Java?

Tags: java, date, standards

I am confused if I can use Instant, `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime` etc. as a data type for my date variable in entity class? Is it possible or should I use `Date` in `Entity` classes and when I do some logic I should convert the Date to some of the types mentioned above?

Thank you!

Comment: It depends on what info of date you want to store

Comment: I understand your confusion. You need to pick according to the need in your specific situation, there is no one and only date/time type to use. Each has its place (except `Date`, it’s poorly designed and long outdated, it hasn’t got any place anymore).

Comment: And Type names are quite meaningful to understand

Comment: Read the javadocs for each. Some represent just date (25th May 2020), some represent date + time (3PM 25th May 2020), some represent date + time + the timezone of the place that date/time applies to, etc (3PM 25th May 2020, GMT)

Comment: If you mean how to save `Date` in your entity class, maybe you can use UTC timestamp in long or UTC string in format like `1994-11-05T13:15:30Z` And then you can convert this UTC time into any type, for example LocalDate based on your current timezone or ZonedDateTime for a specific timezone.

Comment: Did you search for similar questions? Here’s one, for example: [Which date class should I use in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301269/which-date-class-should-i-use-in-java-8) There are more.

Comment: The graphic in [this answer by basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62273365/5772882) could prove quite helpful.